# Laravel HTML Select input save different value in database?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Here I've added simple code but I want to save the different value / number instead of string. the code is following.

```
<select id="select_item" class="form-control" name="sample_collection_type">
   <option value="">Choose your item</option>
   <option value="4500">Watch</option>
   <option value="3000">Bracelet</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="test_amount" class="form-control input_price" readonly>
```

Here I showed the price of the product with javascript

```
<script>
   $('#select_item').on('change', function() {
  $('.input_price').val($(this).val());
});
   
</script>
```

Here I want to save 1 instead of 4500 and accordingly save 2 instead of 3000 into database.

Comment: I don't see any references to 1 & 2 in your code? are they the position/index of the options list inside your HTML?

Comment: What problem are you having with doing this? It should be as simple as an “if” statement in the PHP backend, right before you save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add variable event in function "change". After, you should use e.target.selectedIndex.

```
$('#select_item').on('change', function(e) {
  let index = e.target.selectedIndex;
  $('.input_price').val(index);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u6dgf2m9/3/)

Comment: But I want to show the 4500 after selecting item in the input field and save 1 in the database

Comment: @TiaMat Yes, we can do it. You use e.target.selectedIndex to get index; you use this.value to get value. Now, you can save index or value in the database. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/r1g609uL/12/

Comment: <input type="text" name="test_amount" class="form-control input_price" readonly> but  it saves 4500.

Comment: In fact, input only accepts one value. Either you take the value of option or index of option. So, you should create input with type hidden to send the value to database. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mcxbs0hn/5/

Comment: @TiaMat If my answer is useful, could you please accept my answer? Please click check mark on the left my answer.